three js and cannon js gravity falling apart
I am trying to make those little interractive balls that are on some websites, but when i try to increase the ball size not only do they not get bigger but the gravity falls apart, and i am just so confused.
I just started this project so i might be goind something completely wrong feel free to correct any other mistakes i have probably made.
here is my current code.
whenever I make shape: new CANNON.Sphere(0.5), have a value of 1 or more everything stops moving
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as CANNON from 'cannon-es';

const Balls = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / - 2, 0.1, 5 );
  camera.position.z = 0.5;

  const physicsWorld = new CANNON.World();
  physicsWorld.gravity.set(0, -9.82, 0); // Set gravity

  useEffect(() => {
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: canvasRef.current,
      antialias: true,
    });

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // Create balls
    const balls = [];
    const ballBodies = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const ballGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
        const ballMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        const ballMesh = new THREE.Mesh(ballGeometry, ballMaterial);
        ballMesh.position.set(Math.random() * 10 - 5, Math.random() * 10 - 5, 0);
        scene.add(ballMesh);

        const ballBody = new CANNON.Body({
            mass: 1,
            position: new CANNON.Vec3(ballMesh.position.x, ballMesh.position.y, 0),
            shape: new CANNON.Sphere(0.5),
        });
        physicsWorld.addBody(ballBody);

        balls.push(ballMesh);
        ballBodies.push(ballBody);
    }

    // Add boundaries
    const createPlane = (x, y, z, nx, ny, nz) => {
      const plane = new CANNON.Body({
        mass: 0, // Static
        position: new CANNON.Vec3(x, y, z),
        shape: new CANNON.Plane(),
      });
      plane.quaternion.setFromEuler(nx, ny, nz);
      physicsWorld.addBody(plane);
    };

    // Bottom boundary
    createPlane(0, -window.innerHeight/2, 0, -Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    

    // Top boundary
    createPlane(0, window.innerHeight/2, 0, Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);

    // Left boundary
    createPlane(-window.innerWidth, 0, 0, 0, Math.PI / 2, 0);

    // Right boundary
    createPlane(window.innerWidth, 0, 0, 0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);

    // Backside boundary
    const backWallThickness = 0.5;
    createPlane(0, 0, -2*backWallThickness, 0, 0, 0);

    // Frontside boundary
    const frontWallThickness = 0.5;
    createPlane(0, 0, frontWallThickness, 0, Math.PI, 0); // Rotated by π to face the opposite direction

    // Animate
    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      physicsWorld.step(1 / 60);

      balls.forEach((ball, index) => {
        const body = ballBodies[index];
        ball.position.copy(body.position);
      });

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();

    // Handle mouse events
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
      const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      const mousePosition = new THREE.Vector2();
      mousePosition.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mousePosition.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePosition, camera);
      const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(balls);
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        const ball = intersects[0].object;
        const body = ballBodies[balls.indexOf(ball)];
        const force = new CANNON.Vec3(5, 500, 0);
        body.applyForce(force, body.position);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
  );
};

export default Balls;



I think you are missing body.addShape(groundShape). Pasting the world setup code that works for me in case in helps.
  world = new CANNON.World()

  // Tweak contact properties.
  // Contact stiffness - use to make softer/harder contacts
  world.defaultContactMaterial.contactEquationStiffness = 1e9

  // Stabilization time in number of timesteps
  world.defaultContactMaterial.contactEquationRelaxation = 4

  const solver = new CANNON.GSSolver()
  solver.iterations = 7
  solver.tolerance = 0.1
  world.solver = new CANNON.SplitSolver(solver)
  world.gravity.set(0, -9.81, 0)

  // Create a slippery material (friction coefficient = 0.0)
  physicsMaterial = new CANNON.Material('physics')
  physicsMaterial.friction = 0.01
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
  const physics_physics = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(physicsMaterial, physicsMaterial, {
    friction: 1,
    restitution: 0.3,
  })

  // We must add the contact materials to the world
  world.addContactMaterial(physics_physics)

  // Create the ground plane
  const groundShape = new CANNON.Plane()
  // physicsMaterial.friction = 0
  const groundBody = new CANNON.Body({ 
    mass: 0, 
    type: CANNON.Body.STATIC, 
    material: physicsMaterial,
  })
  groundBody.addShape(groundShape)


